# 404 Not Found when I look for .json file in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My ASP.NET MVC 5 app can't find json files. I'm getting a 404 error when I look for a json file, but if I look for a png file in the same directory it finds that. In web.config I have:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Is there anything else I need to do in Visual Studio to find json files?

Comment: To debug this in future: Say your file is at `http://192.168.0.10?File.json`you'll see a 404 response, however, if you connect from the server itself (eg `http://localhost?File.json`) then it will show a more detailed error message. `404.3 Forbidden that file extension is unknown`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
<system.webServer>
 <staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json; charset=UTF-8" />
 </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

See [adding .json handler support in IIS](http://www.uipress.com/add-json-handler-support-in-iis-7/#.U0SezPldXtI).

Also, ensure the request is not going into the routing framework by putting a breakpoint. (since PNG is served, this is probably not an issue)

Comment: I don't remember adding this to my past projects. But this time it happened (I guess my current IIS doesn't have it enabled by default), and your answer saved me alot of time. I was lucky enough this was the first link I clicked from google. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to go into IIS and add a mimetype for it as well as adding it into your web.config file.